# I cannot understand why the value of "palindrom" changes?

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I cannot understand why the value of "palindrom" changes works when the condition

```
if(palindrome(i*j) ):
```

is replaced with

```
if (palindrome(i*j) and i*j>palindrom)):
```

in this code

```
 def palindrome(n):
     return str(n)==str(n)[::-1];

 def ndigitPalindrome(n):
     lbound=10**(n-1);
     ubound=10**(n);
     palindrom=0;
     for i in range(lbound,ubound):
              for j in range(lbound,ubound):
                  if(palindrome(i*j) ): 
                      palindrom=i*j;
     return palindrom;

 print "Largest n digit palindrome : ",ndigitPalindrome(3);
```

Comment: You don't need trailing semicolons in Python. Ew they're ugly.

Answer (score 2):

`if (palindrome(i*j) and i*j>palindrom))` makes the program produces the largest palindrome by only updating `palindrom` iff the new palindrome is larger, in this case `906609`;

`if(palindrome(i*j) )` makes the program produces the latest palindrome by updating `palindrom` whenever there is a new palindrome, and the order is just the order of the loops, thus it returns in this case `580085` which is generated by `995, 583`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a print statement can help you see what is happening:

```
def ndigitPalindrome(n):
    lbound=10**(n-1)
    ubound=10**(n)
    palindrom=0
    for i in range(lbound,ubound):
        for j in range(lbound,ubound):
            if palindrome(i*j):
                palindrom=i*j
                print i, j, palindrom
    return palindrom
```

---

```
993 913 906609
995 517 514415
995 583 580085
580085
```

The palindromes are not found in ascending order. Checking that `i*j>palindrom` prevents you from changing your palindrome to a smaller value.

essentially your `i*j>palindrom` conditional does the same thing as if you wrote:

```
if is_palindrome(i*j):
    palindrom = max(palindrom, i*j)
```

---

Couple of notes on your code:

```
def n_digit_product_palindrome(n):
    lbound = 10**(n-1)
    ubound = 10**n
    answer = -1
    for i in range(lbound, ubound):
        for j in range(lbound, ubound):
            product = i * j
            if product > answer and is_palindrome(product):
                answer = product
    return answer
​
%timeit n_digit_product_palindrome(3)
print n_digit_product_palindrome(3)

10 loops, best of 3: 138 ms per loop
906609
```

You can reduce the number of products by changing the lbound of the inner loop to the current value of `i`:

```
def n_digit_product_palindrome(n):
    lbound = 10**(n-1)
    ubound = 10**n
    answer = -1
    for i in range(lbound, ubound):
        for j in range(i, ubound):
            product = i * j
            if product > answer and is_palindrome(product):
                answer = product
    return answer

%timeit n_digit_product_palindrome(3)
print n_digit_product_palindrome(3)

10 loops, best of 3: 83.8 ms per loop
906609
```

Using `i` for the `lbound` of the inner loop prevents you from having to check values that you have already encountered. As `i` increments, in the outer loops, all values of `j` less than `i` have already been checked.

For example:

```
lbound = 3
ubound = 6

1st outer loop: i = 3
    inner loop: i * j = 3 * 3, 3 * 4, 3 * 5
2nd outer loop: i = 4
    inner loop: i * j = 4 * 3, 4 * 4, 4 * 5
3rd outer loop: i = 5
    inner loop: i * j = 5 * 3, 5 * 4, 5 * 5
```

becomes:

```
lbound = 3
ubound = 6

1st outer loop: i = 3
    inner loop: i * j = 3 * 3, 3 * 4, 3 * 5
2nd outer loop: i = 4
    inner loop: i * j = 4 * 4, 4 * 5
3rd outer loop: i = 5
    inner loop: i * j = 5 * 5
```

Reversing your search can greatly improve the runtime by allowing you to exit early:

```
def n_digit_product_palindrome(n):
    ubound = 10**n-1
    lbound = 10**(n-1)-1
    answer = -1
    for i in range(ubound, lbound, -1):
        if i * i < answer:
            break
        for j in range(i, lbound, -1):
            product = i * j
            if product < answer:
                break
            if product > answer and is_palindrome(product):
                answer = product
    return answer

%timeit n_digit_product_palindrome(3)
print n_digit_product_palindrome(3)

100 loops, best of 3: 5.47 ms per loop
906609
```

Break the outer loop when you find `i * i < answer` because when descending values of `i`, if the current `i * i` is less than the value of a palindrome you've found, no subsequent values of `i` and `j` will produce a larger value.

For the inner loop, the break logic is similar because when `i * j` is less than the answer no subsequent values of `j` times current `i` will produce a value greater than answer.